# div centering doesn't work

Tags: html, css, centering

I have the menu on the bottom of the page, and I'm trying to center the wrapper `div`

with logo and buttons inside the doc. The `centering` doesn't work. Can you guys tell me why?

I want the logo to float to the left, and buttons to float to the right, but the wrapper `div` must be centered.

Here's the code:

```css
html,body {
  min-width:320px;
  min-height:320px;
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:0;
  font-size:68px;
  font-weight:700;
}

.header-wrapper {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/1500x646");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  height:645px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:120px;
}

.slider-wrapper2 {
  background-color:white;
  height:645px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:120px;
}


.slider1 {
  padding-top:120px;
}

.navigation {
  max-width:1170px;
  height:94px;
  background-color:white;
}

nav {
  float:right;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#626262;
  padding:40px 20px 40px 20px;
  margin:0;
  background-color:#dfbb42;
}
a:hover {
  color:white;
}

#logo {
  float:left;
  margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Random title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet"> 

  
</head>

<body>

<section>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <h1>Just some random text</h1>
  </div>
</section>


<section id="menu2">
  <div class="navigation">
    <nav>
    <a href="" id="home">Home</a>
    <a href="" id="menu2" style="background-color:honeydew">Menu 2</a>
    <a href="" id="menu3" style="background-color:lightblue">Menu 3</a>
    <a href="" id="menu4" style="background-color:red">Menu 4</a>
    <a href="" id="menu5" style="background-color:yellow">Menu 5</a>
  </nav>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x70" alt="Logo" id="logo">
</div>
</section>

<section id="menu3">
  <div class="text-boxes">
    <img src="images/slider-buttons/typography/typography-icon.jpg">
  </div>
</section>

<section id="menu4">
  <div class="picture-boxes">
  <p>parapap</p>
  </div>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To center a block level element horizontally, the easiest method is to apply a `width` and set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` (or `margin: auto;` or `margin: 0 auto;`).

Since you already have a width on `.navigation`, just apply `margin: auto` to `.navigation` and it will center horizontally.

```css
html,body {
  min-width:320px;
  min-height:320px;
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:0;
  font-size:68px;
  font-weight:700;
}

.header-wrapper {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/1500x646");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  height:645px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:120px;
}

.slider-wrapper2 {
  background-color:white;
  height:645px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:120px;
}


.slider1 {
  padding-top:120px;
}

.navigation {
  max-width:1170px;
  height:94px;
  background-color:white;
  margin: auto;
}

nav {
  float:right;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#626262;
  padding:40px 20px 40px 20px;
  margin:0;
  background-color:#dfbb42;
}
a:hover {
  color:white;
}

#logo {
  float:left;
  margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Random title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet"> 

  
</head>

<body>

<section>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <h1>Just some random text</h1>
  </div>
</section>


<section id="menu2">
  <div class="navigation">
    <nav>
    <a href="" id="home">Home</a>
    <a href="" id="menu2" style="background-color:honeydew">Menu 2</a>
    <a href="" id="menu3" style="background-color:lightblue">Menu 3</a>
    <a href="" id="menu4" style="background-color:red">Menu 4</a>
    <a href="" id="menu5" style="background-color:yellow">Menu 5</a>
  </nav>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x70" alt="Logo" id="logo">
</div>
</section>

<section id="menu3">
  <div class="text-boxes">
    <img src="images/slider-buttons/typography/typography-icon.jpg">
  </div>
</section>

<section id="menu4">
  <div class="picture-boxes">
  <p>parapap</p>
  </div>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! But the elements are centered horizontally, and I need them to be centered both vertically and horizontally. How do I do this (I'm really bad at positioning)? Also, I need the .navigation to stick to the bottom of the screen when the page is loaded but it has to smoothly switch from the bottom to the top when you scroll down the page. I think that it can be solved with jQuery (changing attributes while scrolling) but how to stick it to the bottom first?

Answer (score 1):

By default html elements are left aligned. (like your .navigation)
if you add a `margin:auto` on a block element(note: wrapper div is a block element) it will add up the remaining space to the viewport and add a `left-margin` and `right-margin` to the block element, so it will look centered.
So, giving a `margin:auto` styling to the wrapper div will do the job.

just like this:

```css
html,body {
  min-width:320px;
  min-height:320px;
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:0;
  font-size:68px;
  font-weight:700;
}

.header-wrapper {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/1500x646");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  height:645px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:120px;
}

.slider-wrapper2 {
  background-color:white;
  height:645px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:120px;
}


.slider1 {
  padding-top:120px;
}

.navigation {
  max-width:1170px;
  height:94px;
  background-color:white;
  margin:0 auto;
}

nav {
  float:right;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#626262;
  padding:40px 20px 40px 20px;
  margin:0;
  background-color:#dfbb42;
}
a:hover {
  color:white;
}

#logo {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Random title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet"> 

  
</head>

<body>

<section>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <h1>Just some random text</h1>
  </div>
</section>


<section id="menu2">
  <div class="navigation">
    <nav>
    <a href="" id="home">Home</a>
    <a href="" id="menu2" style="background-color:honeydew">Menu 2</a>
    <a href="" id="menu3" style="background-color:lightblue">Menu 3</a>
    <a href="" id="menu4" style="background-color:red">Menu 4</a>
    <a href="" id="menu5" style="background-color:yellow">Menu 5</a>
  </nav>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x70" alt="Logo" id="logo">
</div>
</section>

<section id="menu3">
  <div class="text-boxes">
    <img src="images/slider-buttons/typography/typography-icon.jpg">
  </div>
</section>

<section id="menu4">
  <div class="picture-boxes">
  <p>parapap</p>
  </div>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```